# Create an abstract class and infer private attributes to subclasses

Tags: java

I have an abstract class and two subclasses which have 4 attributes in common that SHOULD be private acces only, i cant seem to find the way of making this without defining the attributes in each subclass.

```
public abstract class Cuenta {

protected long numeroCuenta;
protected String titular;
protected long saldo = 0;

public void depositar(long monto){
    saldo += monto;
}

public abstract void extraer(long monto);

}


public class CajaAhorro extends Cuenta {


public CajaAhorro(long nCuenta, String titular){
    super.numeroCuenta = nCuenta;
    super.titular = titular;


}

@Override
public void extraer(long monto){

    if (monto > saldo) throw new  RuntimeException("No hay dinero suficiente" );
    saldo -= monto;
}
}

public class CuentaCorriente extends Cuenta {
private long descubierto;

public CuentaCorriente(long nCuenta, String titular, long descubierto){
    super.numeroCuenta = nCuenta;
    super.titular = titular;
    this.descubierto = descubierto;
}

@Override
public void extraer(long monto){
    if (monto > saldo + descubierto) throw new  RuntimeException("No hay dinero suficiente" );
    saldo -= monto;
   }
 }
```

The problem with this is that i need a constructor for cuentaCorriente that recibes also descubierto.

Comment: Your analysis is correct. Do you have any questions to us?

Comment: how should i do it....

Comment: How should you do _what_?